# Why is a one line non-understandable answer used as review audit?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know

- Why the following answer good and used as review audit?
- What the answer is supposed to mean
- and in conjunction with the first question - how I am supposed to figure this out?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a link to the question or answer you're talking about? Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander http://askubuntu.com/questions/775025/how-to-detect-the-number-of-opened-terminals-by-the-user/775035#775035

Comment: @MarkKirby The answer got its upvotes while it still had a "body". The poster obviously didn't believe in it anymore and edited it into the one-liner

Comment: @JacobVlijm Oh I see now, I think that needs to be reverted but I don't know where to, it has had 53 revisions..

Comment: @MarkKirby might be a good thing. This is kind of voting- misleading. People voted for something the answer isn't anymore.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I reverted it to its first version, that seems a solid answer, I have know idea why OP kept editing it.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Perhaps the best thing is just to have it removed before it cause more controversy.

Comment: @MarkKirby yeah, maybe if OP wants to keep the +155, he should be given a few days to do one more edit, pick the (in his opinion) closest option and explain what are the downsides, when it works, when not.

Comment: @JacobVlijm That seems like a good way.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I left them a comment, they have logged in today, so are still active. I directed them here and explained about a possible deletion, lets wait and see what they say.

Comment: @ByteCommander This to you too ^

Comment: I probably would have failed this audit too.

Comment: I am very curious to know, who voted this down and why? I cannot think of any reason this is a bad post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The system's decision to take this answer as reviewer test was correct, as it is an accepted and well upvoted answer.

However, I agree that this answer *as it currently stands* should *not* have been accepted and upvoted like this. It does really clearly not meet the site's quality standards.

- The answer is not providing a solution, but simply saying "You can't!"
- There is not even the lightest effort to explain why the answerer thinks their post is correct or how they come to this conclusion.
- The answer makes unnecessary use of heavy formatting (H1 title and blockquote box) to highlight a not really helpful word
- The highlighted word, which is actually the main part of the answer, has an obvious and almost painful typo in it (it's "*unobtainable*", duh!)

---

However, looking at [the post's revisions site](https://askubuntu.com/posts/775029/revisions), we see that it got **edited 53 times**! And only the last edit 19 hours ago removed all the possibly useful content and reduced it to this misspelled single word.

The last edit made the post no longer deserving this accepted status and especially its high score. But not sure what we should do in this case? I doubt rolling back the last edit would be the right choice, as the author decided that the previous content is no longer valid. I can't verify whether that's true or not - it should be flagged for moderator attention anyway. They must discuss how to handle it.

Comment: I flagged it for a mod, pointing them here as to why, good answer.

Comment: Good wording. No clue what should be done though.

Comment: @MarkKirby I just flagged it as well, linking this Q here... :)

Comment: Given the fact that review audits [are selected by algorithms only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189000/how-are-review-audit-posts-selected), there's no way of avoiding such strange audits except suggest a review for review audits (relatively few work for reviewers since #audits << #reviews). Give the fact that such extreme edits are extremely rare and that one won't drop all reviewer skill after experiencing such an audit as above, it's tolerable that this happens imo. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of review audits is automated; it's based totally on the votes and accepting of the answer.  I learned that lesson the hard way with a similar review audit that I failed:

[image]

**Please notice: the top comment (12 upvotes) says this is not an answer.**

## Update:

Hilarious.  I just got another review audit on another answer on the same question.  Except this time [I passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRVLU.png).  The funny thing is that I would not have flagged this second one: it was at least an answer.  I just left a comment saying that the answer had nothing to do with Ubuntu.

## Another Update:

What's up with this question?  I just got a **third** review audit on **yet another** answer to the same question.  This time, I really liked the answer, [so I upvoted it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpqbJ.png).  In my opinion, this is the right answer.  It gave an answer **about Ubuntu** that validly pointed out that white noise is harsh, but also gave a solution.

Comment: You should also notice that the OP (who is a mod) says it is an answer (and that comment has 11 upvotes, one fewer than the top comment).

Comment: Fair enough.  Just saying that there are times you can honestly disagree with the review audits.  At the same time, I appreciate them as they are holding me and the other reviewers accountable.