# I'm really not very pleased with the audit system

Tags: discussion

So I was reviewing this answer:

> Install this:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
> ```

I [failed the audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/573784) because that answer turned out to be plagiarism.

Well O.K.... fine, it deserves to be removed, but... **How was I supposed to know that?!**

Comment: Nothing automated in life can be perfect (At least not yet), it can only get better by reporting those imperfections when found so they get fixed. Can you add a link to the audit so we can help a bit more?

Comment: FYI The best way to deal with audits, if you suspect one, is visit the original question and see what is going on, there only purpose is to make sure you are paying attention but sometimes they can go badly wrong http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15451/why-is-a-one-line-non-understandable-answer-used-as-review-audit

Comment: @MarkKirby - Thanks for the tip! I did suspect it, because the system identified it as possible spam.

Comment: Also, if in doubt, press skip.

Comment: @MarkKirby - <Sigh> this is a stupid question, but how do I view my reviewing history so I can find the failed audit?

Comment: Quickest way, look in your browser history, don't think there is an audit history in profile.

Comment: @Dan - Hyperlink added.

Comment: It is right, you can see Muru flagged it from his comment, it was the same as another answer. Not sure about the `spam` reason myself, should perhaps be removed for `length and content`. You just got a tricky one. Skip when in doubt, you only had the privilege for a day, when you get more experience, they mostly stick out like a sore thumb, mostly...

Comment: @MarkKirby - Muru's comment wasn't visible when I reviewed.

Comment: I know, audits are supposed to trick you. Edit ones will add random words in amongst the text and others will show an answer was voted down when it is actually +10 and accepted, it is to trick you and make you pay attention, if in doubt open the original question.

Comment: @MarkKirby - Yeah, the "community" user added a bunch of random stuff in an edit. It was plainly obvious it was an audit.

Comment: You can see your review history here:  http://askubuntu.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=reviews - "It was plainly obvious it was an audit" that's because they are only designed to make sure you're actually paying attention. (It doesn't actually show you that the "Community" user added the "bunch of random stuff" until _after_ you pass the audit BTW, though.)

Comment: Looks like I also fell for this tricky review audit. :/

Comment: @edwinksl - <sigh>